# HSQLDB with CSV Table source - Date format not accepted

Tags: date, csv, hsqldb

I'm trying to get a simple CSV file as source for a HSQL database. 
I'm blocked at the date, getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: bad TEXT table source file - line number: 1 org.hsqldb.HsqlException: data exception: invalid datetime format in statement [SET TABLE Patient SOURCE "queryDbTest.csv;fs=,;vs=,"]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
```

I have tried many variations, all failed with the same error. The file is being read, and in debugging it I see it is failing at parsing the a date which is, so far as i understand, in the correct date format.

My code is as follows

```
    System.setProperty("textdb.allow_full_path", "true");

    Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:mymemdb", "SA", "");

    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    st.execute("CREATE TEXT TABLE Patient (" +
                    "HospitalNumber VARCHAR(100), " +
                    "NHS_Number VARCHAR(100), " +
                    "Name VARCHAR(100), " +
                    "other_names VARCHAR(100), " +
                    "dob Date, " +
                    "address VARCHAR(200))");

    st.execute("SET TABLE Patient SOURCE \"" + "queryDbTest.csv" + ";all_quoted=true;fs=,;qc=\\quote\"");
```

and my CSV

```
'1234', 'N998877', 'Smith', 'Mary', '1999-12-01', 'an address 1'
```

Variations i have tried include:

1. Using 'DateTime' as a column type instead
2. Using the DateTime format in the CSV file  (i..e, yyyy-MM-dd
   HH:mm:ss)
3. Using a timestamp format in the CSV (i.e., yyyy-MM-dd
   HH:mm:ss.SSSSS)
4. Using null as a value for date in the CSV.
5. With word 'DATE' before the date value in the csv file

In all cases, I get the same results.... a complaint about datetime format.

I'm using hsqldb-2.3.4

Any ideas?

Comment: Have modified my example code above to reflect the most recent attempt, after suggestion from fredt

Answer (score 0):

In the TEXT table source file, the DATE column should be the data string, without the word DATE.

```
'1234', 'N998877', 'Smith', 'Mary', '1999-12-01', 'an address 1'
```

As you are using the single-quote as the quote character, you should specify it as the `qc`

```
st.execute("SET TABLE Patient SOURCE \"" + "queryDbTest.csv" + ";all_quoted=true;fs=,;qc=\\apos\"");
```

You can see the expected format by setting the table text source to a non-existent file and inserting and committing a single row of data using JDBC. The row will be saved in the new file with the format variables that you have set up.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Actually, the 'DATE' word in the source was an artifact of one of my many attempts. I remove it and it unfortunately does not seem to change things. I have now also tried using the qc option, as you suggested, but to no avail. Tried is as : st.execute("SET TABLE Patient SOURCE \"" + "queryDbTest.csv" + ";all_quoted=true;fs=,;qc=\\quote\""); A single escape will not compile.

Comment: I tried using a non-existent filepath for the source. On execution of the "SET TABLE Patient" command, it throws an exception to say that the file does not exist. I thought perhaps it has something to do with the property I set above (textdb.allow_full_path) so I comment out that line;  after which it throws an exception already at the "CREATE TEXT TABLE" statement !!  I wonder what could be the cause of the discrepancy between what I see and you see.

Comment: The textdb.allow_full_path property is OK. You execute CREATE TABLE only once. You can then use SET TABLE to assign a new file to the table.

Comment: corrected the answer to use `apos` as quote character instead of `quote`